# How to remove all networks from my Facebook profile?

Tags: facebook

How can I remove all networks from my Facebook profile including the main network that is displayed beside the name?

First, I could not find any network configurations in the profile options, but following [this link](https://www.facebook.com/settings?section=networks) found in the Facebook help section, I can see and add networks. The problem is, I can't find a way to completely remove all networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **How do I leave a network?**
>   To leave a supported network:
>
> 1. Open the Account dropdown menu at the top right corner of Facebook and choose **Account Settings**.
> 2. Click [Edit](http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=account&section=networks&t) next to Networks.
> 3. Click **Remove** next to the network name you wish to remove.
> 4. Click **Save Changes**.

From [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=211269705571231).

**EDIT:**

It seems that you can no longer remove your primary network:
[image]

**EDIT 02/10/2011:**

It seems that you are now able again to remove your primary network. I just did it. There is a new **Remove** link next to your primary network and... voilà!

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I found that too but can't find any "remove" link. Have you actually tried this?

Comment: I did it a while ago and it worked, but you are right, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @TimBüthe check my new edit to the original answer.

Comment: Seems like they fixed that!

Comment: It seems that although you can remove it, when you go to save and look at it again it re-appears? How do I keep it at NO network?